# IPython %cpaste command freezes in Terminal mode

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste

I try to use IPython's `%cpaste` to paste the clipboard content (Python code) to my Terminal which is launched via Neovim's terminal mode.

However, if I paste long lines of code, it freezes, and does not respond to my input at all. I'm forced to exit of it using keyboard interrupt, but then I could not run any code.

The result is like the following, and the code does not scroll toward the bottom (i.e. the part of code is cut off, as only the code that a page contains seems to be pasted).

Why is the `%cpaste` command to paste my code not working and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: [Please, please, please, do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). That just hurts my eyes with the transparency

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `%paste`?

I tried it in VIM terminal and `%paste` works for me in `VIM-8 terminal`